# Can I do this in DataGrid Style?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I was wondering if it's possible to put the CellStyle, ColumnHeaderStyle, and RowStyle inside a DataGrid Style?

For Example:

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle2" TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow"/>
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
    <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle2}"/>
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeader2}"/>
    <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle2}"/>
</Style>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" Height="149.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
              Style="{Binding DataGridStyle2}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
       ....
      <DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: did you try it and it didn't work ?

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it didn't work. I was looking for a solution to be able to consolidate related styles into one keyed style.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is `YES` you can set the style in the dataGrid style since `CellStyle` itself is a DP for a datagrid so you can set it just like other `Dependency Properties` in the style.